# iOS SwiftUI WidgetKit: My widgets don’t show up in the ‘Add Widgets’ section

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, widgetkit

I developed an app with 10 widgets but some iPhone, iPad or macOS users report that my widgets or the "App Name" don't appear in the widgets list when they tried to add the widgets of my app.

There's no way I can replicate the problem, but the number of the users that report this issue is growing up every day.

It’s not clear if the problem is caused by the iPhone model, a crash on the widget preview or other factors.

My widgets previews are built reading static data, so this data is the same in every conditions.

I suggest my users to do the following steps:

- Start the app and go to check again if "App name" appears among widget List
- Close every app and restart the device; then start the app and
  go to check again if "App name" appears among widget List
- Temporarily change system language and turn on Bold Text and go to check again if "App Name" appears among widget List
- Uninstall and reinstall the app, start the app and go to check again if "App Name" appears among widget List

But all users who have tried these steps say that the app still does not appear in the list of widgets.

The following code is the one I use inside the main widgets swift file called TodayWidgetExtension:

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI


struct PlaceholderView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("loading")
    }
}


//MARK: - Main widget bundle configuration
@main
struct WidgetBundle: WidgetBundle {
    @WidgetBundleBuilder
    var body: some Widget {
        
//MARK: - 1
        Widget1Large() //IntentConfiguration
        Widget1Medium() //StaticConfiguration
        Widget1Small() //StaticConfiguration
        if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 16.0, *) {
            Widget1Accessory() //StaticConfiguration
        }
        
//MARK: - 2
        Widget2Large() //StaticConfiguration

//MARK: - 3
        #if !targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        Widget3Medium() //StaticConfiguration
        #endif
        
//MARK: - 4
        Widget4Large() //StaticConfiguratio
        
//MARK: - 5
        Widget5Medium() //IntentConfiguration
        
//MARK: - 6
        Widget6Large() //IntentConfiguration
        Widget6Medium() //IntentConfiguration
        
    }
}

struct todaywidgetextension_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PlaceholderView()
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))
    }
}
```

The only thing that I've noticed debugging the widgets extension is that, even if I don't add any of them to my iPhone screen, Xcode tells me that widgets occupied 20mb of memory (the limit for widgets is 30mb). I tried removing all the widgets from the above code leaving only one (Widget1Small for example), but Xcode continues to tell me that 20mb of memory are still occupied.

I hope that someone can help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Don't have small, medium, large in there. Just have Widget1() .. Widget6(). Inside each Widget (example Widget1) have a switch on widgetFamily (environment value) to display the correct size. Refer to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/building_widgets_using_widgetkit_and_swiftui

Comment: Hi @user1046037 thank you for your answer, do you think that this is the problem? Do you think this is why some users don't see them or is this an optimization tip? I'm using different widgets for different sizes because unfortunately they have different configurations (some static, some with intent). Is there a way to choose different configurations within the same widget?

Comment: @user1046037, I updated the question with the configuration info, another problem is that the provider loads different data in relation to the family of widget. Is there a way to read the family of the widget from the provider?

Comment: Yes I think that is the reason for the issue, so first fix that. Use `@Environment(\.widgetFamily) private var widgetFamily` to detect the widget family

Comment: Always spend some time learning the framework and watch all WWDC videos on WidgetKit, though it might take time, it will serve you better in the longer run

Comment: I have the same issues. @user1046037 are you suggesting to return only the specific widget size in `@WidgetBundleBuilder` body depending on `@Environment(\.widgetFamily) private var widgetFamily` switch case?! But a widget `entryView` may support multiple families (sizes) having a widgetFamily switch in the body...

Comment: @AlmasAdilbek `WidgetBundle` should only contain unique widgets, example `WidgetA`, `WidgetB` etc. `WidgetA` would contain a view which would show different content depending on the `widgetFamily` environment value. So **DO NOT** have `WidgetASmall`, `WidgetAMedium`, `WidgetBLarge` in your `WidgetBundle`. Refer to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/building_widgets_using_widgetkit_and_swiftui

Comment: @user1046037 thank you for your suggestions, I always spent a lot of time on apple documentation but I still don't find a way  to read "widget family" from TimelineProvider or IntentTimelineProvider. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @user1046037 Another question is: WidgetA and WidgetB are similiar but they are using different classes, different "kind", in some cases different "provider", different configuration, description and supported family. System should see them like different widgets, so why I should group them? We can't create more than 5 widgets? Thank you..

Comment: Use `@Environment(\.widgetFamily) private var widgetFamily` this is an environment variable that you could use in any view. I had already mentioned in the previous comments

Comment: Don't group WidgetA and WidgetB into the same widget, only the small, medium and large size of the same widget needs to be grouped. Please read all my previous comments. There is no limit on the number of widgets as far as I know but it is wrong to WidgetASmall and WidgetAMedium and WidgetALarge in the widget bundle (like in your question). Sizes need to be determined by the view inside the widget. Please read all my previous comments again and refer to the sample project link provided in my previous comment.

Comment: I'm sorry @user1046037, maybe I'm not explaining well. I have read all your comments and I understand your suggestions perfectly. I already knew @Environment(\.widgetFamily) private var widgetFamily but my problem is that I need to know the widgetFamily from TimelineProvider or IntentTimelineProvider because I need to load different data with different sizes of the same widget. So, for this reason, if the provider provides different data I probably have to create different widgets. What do you think?

Comment: Timeline provider functions would have a `context` parameter of the type`TimelineProviderContext`. From there you can determine widgetFamily. Just use `context.family`. Refer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/timelineprovidercontext

Comment: have you solve the problems yet?, its appear to happened to me also right now?